# How can I change console shell's resolution in ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, resolution, console, grub

How can I change console shell's resolution?

By this I mean the shell when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
I'm running Ubuntu 9.10, I thought this could be done by changing grub's `menu.lst` file by with grub2 I really don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to change the aspect of the console (virtual terminal) or of the GRUB boot loader? It seems to be the first, so in this case the **grub2** tag should be removed.

Comment: No, the bootloader config determines the console resolution, so the grub2 tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Identify a block that looks like this (your current running kernel):

```
menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-14-generic" {
    recordfail=1
    if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
set quiet=1
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,1)
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e5ce0bc0-d1b0-4802-a6d4-3fd9fc0e7e58
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-14-generic root=UUID=e5ce0bc0-d1b0-4802-a6d4-3fd9fc0e7e58 ro   quiet splash
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-14-generic
}
```

Edit the "linux ..." line and, at the end (after "quiet splash"), leave a blank and add something like "vga=773" or another code, depending on the resolution. Here is [a list of codes](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsharpshells.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F21509401044%2Flinux-kernel-vga-modes&date=2012-04-21) for various resolutions.

Reboot and the new resolution should be enabled.

---

The provided link gives a list of modes on one particular system; with the 'hwinfo' utility you can generate a list of modes for your system as follows:

```
hwinfo --framebuffer
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that i found out that grub.cfg is not meant to be edited (thats why its in read-only mode). So next time something or someone executes update-grub2 the option will be overwritten.
Thank you, if i find out how to do it properly i'll edit my post.

Comment: Well, you just have to figure out which file it reads *from* in order to generate grub.cfg. You can always grep through all of `/etc/` for your uuid or some other unique string that the source file would need to contain.

Comment: MikeH's answer (http://superuser.com/questions/66428/how-can-i-change-console-shells-resolution-in-ubuntu-9-10/73116#73116) appears to work and does not require editting auto generated files.

Answer (score 9):

To add custom boot options to your boot linux from grub 2, you need to edit

`/etc/default/grub`

find the line that reads

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and change it to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vga=ask"`

if you know your exact vga= number is, then put that in instead of "ask"

After you edit any of grubs files in /etc you should run

`update-grub`

to apply the changes

Comment: It says "ask parameter no longer supported"

Answer (score 4):

According this excellent howto http://harrison3001.blogspot.com/2009/09/grub-2-graphical-boot-tips-to-set.html it works for me on Ubuntu-Server-9.10.

With the following additions in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="gfxpayload=true"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x1200x32  
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="vbe"
```

Resolution can be found out via:

```
hwinfo --framebuffer
```

I read that x32 is a must.

And modification of `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE} <-- FIND THIS LINE
```

(as you note GRUB_GFXMODE is the variable we set before through `/etc/default/grub`)

```
set gfxpayload=keep <-- THIS IS FOR THE VGA CONSOLE!
```

(as you note the statement keep, obviously, keeps, what?, the resolution we set before through `GRUB_GFXMODE` variable set into `/etc/default/grub`)

```
insmod gfxterm
insmod ${GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND}
```

then run `update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, vga=ask as well as similar to vga=796 does not work, at least not on my system (acer aspir 5532 laptop). Similar to vga=798 gives me a warning after the grub menu that goes by a bit to fast for me to read (probably in /var/logs somewhere), but it starts with "vga=798 is deprecated", then continues to boot. My vt's are then standard resolution (whatever that is, 800x640?). Giving it vga=ask gives me a "no longer supported" error after grub, "press any key to continue." Pressing a key gives me a "you have to load a kernel first" error and goes back to grub, after which it repeats. To get out of that I had to press "e" in grub and edit the arguments before booting. Guess I could have gone to recovery mode instead and edited /etc/default/grub then run update-grub. If I find something that works I'll post it here, morning the loss of /boot/grub/menu.lst all the while.

Comment: if it's a kernel output msg it should be recorded in `dmesg` (/var/log/dmesg; just issue the command `dmesg`, but it's a lot of output, so `dmesg | head` is perhaps more useful).

Answer (score 0):

Boot with the `vga=ask` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try holding the shift key down while booting.  when the menu appears press c for the commandline and then enter "vbeinfo" this will give you a list of supported resolutions for your videocard.  It might be that the number representing what you want is there. on mine for example 1152x864x32 is 0x156  I am thinking this 156 number may be what it is looking for?

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to switch back to Grub 1, if you can figure out how. It should be doable, because Karmic still supports Grub 1 for computers that upgrade from 9.04 and earlier versions.